# name 'pyproj' is not defined

Tags: python, pyproj

I am trying to use **pyproj** and **transform** but I have an error **name 'pyproj' is not defined**.
I check my environment and I can see the **pyproj** version 2.6.0. My **python** version is 3.7.3. So, what's going wrong there? Why pyproj is not defined?

```
project = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(example1.crs), pyproj.Proj(example2.crs))
```

Comment: Is there any more to your script? Have you done an `import pyproj` at the beginning?

Comment: I was running the same code for a lot of months without problem. This line is the error. It's the first line of my code, the example1 and example2 are geodataframes. I must import partial and transform from scratch now and I am wondering if this is coming maybe from upgrading the versions.

Comment: It can't be the first line of your code unless you're working in some environment where pyproj is already imported. If you add `import pyproj` before that line, what happens?

Comment: Thank you, I solve the issue. It's true I have pyproj in my environment but something was broken so that's why I couldn't use pyproj.